# Firebase - order items according to server time

Tags: firebase

I want to maintains user comments as an ordered list, based on the server write-time. A couple of questions regarding that:

1. Can I create (set / push) a locations based on ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?
2. Can I validate (1) with rules?
3. Can I safely assume that no two posts will be written at the exact "same moment", overriding eachother?
4. If I decide to use setWithPriority, and not order by the location-name, can I use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP for the priority (and validate it by rules....)
5. "Bonus" question - Is there still no way to create a COUNT query in firebase?

=== EDIT ===

I'm trying to achieve a chat-like feature. Messages must be ordered chronologically (by a server-side timestamp) in order to maintain a logical order for "discussion" (if I'll use a client-generated order than one local's machine clock offset could ruin the entire discussion). I can use rules to validate that a ServerValue.TIMESTAMP field is persisted to any new message, however, I can't seem to find a way to make sure that clients actually use setWithPriority() in order to persist data. I can't figure out any way to do this - am i missing something?

Comment: #3 is a big "no". If your application sees widespread adoption, this statement will become unmaintainable. I would instead simply use `push` to guarantee uniqueness and keep the timestamp in a value and/or set it as the priority.

Comment: All of this is covered in the docs under [saving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) and [retrieving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html). Those are a great read to get up to speed on such things.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen - doesn't "push" rely on client-side timestamp? if so how can i be sure that order is kept?

Comment: `push` just guarantees a unique id. If you use the server-side timestamp to set the priority, you can use that to maintain order. But there is no guarantee of uniqueness in such timestamps: the messages of two people could arrive on the server at the exact same moment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Thanks, I understand what you're saying. Right now though, I have a problem that I need to rely on clients to actually setWithPriority. Is there any way for me to get the chronologically-sorted list of messages without this assumption? Can I somehow ask FB to give me the messages based on the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP field?

Answer (score 4):

1. you can either `.push()` which generates auto ID as key or you can `.setWithPriority()` where your key can be anything and the priority can be pretty much anything as well.  As far as I'm aware there is no option to have `serverValue.TIMESTAMP` as a key. The only way is to retrieve it  and explicitly set it as the key with `.child(retrievedTime).set(someData)`
2. see 1)
3. Not sure what you mean exactly since there is no option to set `servervalue` as a key, but IMHO this is one of the reasons why is it so.
4. You can use some field on database and set `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and listen for the change - in the callback you will get the most current server time pretty much ASAP as the placeholder is replaced with `TIMESTAMP`. However there is no guarantee that it is going to be unique. It is perfectly legitimate to have to records with the same priority.
5. It is promised, but not yet available. You you can do it manually with transactions on every write/delete see [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html)

Comment: 4 - ServerValue can be set as the priority using setWithPriority(data, Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP), which I think was the question here. 5 - Or on the client by using snapshot.numChildren() after grabbing the records;

Comment: @Kato re. snapshot.numChildren() - what about snapshot with 20mil+ children? would you use it?

Comment: Certainly not. The right tool for the right job. For 20mil children, I would maintain a counter. Even a server side query that performed a count would be slow and arduous at that point.

Comment: @Kato precisely :) point 5) transactions is the right tool to do the counter.

Comment: They are both valid tools. 20mil children is not a common use case, but certainly a valid one.